# Link to Taxononomy from subweb quicklaunch

Tags: development, central-administration, taxonomy, permissions

Is it possible to create somehow link from some subweb (link is for example placed in quick launch but it's not necessary to be there) to taxonomy page (central administration). For now, I don't know how do that but I assume that I should in some way elevate privileges (to became admin) for any regular user of my subweb. 
Precisely, I would like to give possibility to regular subweb users to modify taxonomy (CRUD operations).

Have somebody some suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that you link to the taxonomy page through Site Settings, rather than Central Administration. The link will be something like /_layouts/termstoremanager.aspx.